I want to input a list of solana addresses and return the number of swap transactions for each address
I want to input a list of solana addresses and return the number of swap transactions for each address.
I'm trying to figure this out but fairly new to this coding environment.
Any help or pointing in the right direction would be appreciated.
I am trying to find resources to help.

Hey, you can use the @solana/web3.js sdk and get the events of an account and filter them out to see if any event is related to a swap transaction or no.
